# Conflict between two action filter attribute

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, minify, bundling-and-minification

I have implemented two action filter one for HTML minification and another one for moving script to the end of the page.

For HTML minification I am using NuGet package WebMarkupMin and for moving inline script to the bottom of my page I am using NuGet package BundleMinifyInlineJsCss.

To implement BundleMinifyInlineJsCss I have followed this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/bundling-and-minifying-inline-css-and-js).

I have globally declared both of these filters from Global.asax.cs file like below order:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new MinifyHtmlAttribute());
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new ReplaceTagsAttribute());
```

For ReplaceTagsAttribute I have use OnActionExecuting method like below:

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext){
    var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
    if (response.Filter == null) return; // <-----
        response.Filter = new BundleAndMinifyResponseFilter(response.Filter);
 }
```

But if I use both of these filters together, it generates minification code twise. Hence I am facing an issue like this in Firebug:

> History.js Adapter has already been loaded"

Please note if I add filter - `GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new ReplaceTagsAttribute());` then only issue occurs.

How can I fix this?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i suspect if your ReplaceTagsAttribute is using that file too ??

Comment: I am not getting you. Can you please explain me?

Comment: Do you mind sharing code of your both the action filter attributes ??

Comment: As I mentioned in my question  I use NuGet package.

Comment: apologies...when you use your scripts file...is your History.js file added twice... ?? or is it dependent on any other JS...

Comment: No, this is added only once. Moreover, if I comment the line for second filter then minification works fine without any error. Not only this, rather than this I am facing some other issues as well. It breaks my page as I use JS to load some content